# anchor tag not working in saleforce1 on android?

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app

i have facing issue in Saleforce1 anchor tag on android phones ,the link is not open in saleforce1 ,
here is my Code

```
<apex:page >

      <a href="/001?fcf=00Bi0000006Ezi7" >All Accounts List View Reltive </a> 

 </apex:page>
```

All list views links are not working on Android but it working on Iphone and web browser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Salesforce1, you must use the JavaScript functions in `sforce.one` to navigate to URLs, records, list views, etc rather than HTML links - see the documentation on [Managing Navigation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/salesforce1/Content/vf_dev_best_practices_navigation.htm). In this case, you would use `navigateToList`, like this:

```
<apex:page >
  <a href="javascript:sforce.one.navigateToList('00Bi0000006Ezi7', 'All Accounts', '001');">
    All Accounts
  </a>
</apex:page>
```

- `listViewId` is self-explanatory
- `listViewName` will be shown as the header for the list view (it can be essentially any string - it doesn't need to be the same as the list view's actual name)
- `scope` is the three character object ID, for Account, this is `001`.